# Marginal probability mass function

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I have the joint PMF

$\exp(y_1 \ln(\lambda)+y_2 \ln(c)+y_2\ln(\lambda)-\ln(y_1!y_2!)-\lambda(1+c))$

for a constant $c>0$. In canonical representation and mixed parameterization I have $\mathbf{\theta}=(\ln(c),\ln(\lambda))$ and $\mathbf{t}=(v,u)^T$ with $v=Y_2$ and $u=Y_1+Y_2$.

What is the marginal PMF $f(v)$?

Comment: Do you have $y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{N}_0$?

Comment: Do you have $y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{N}_0$? If this is true, then $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, $Y_1$ has Poisson distribution $Po(\lambda)$ and $Y_2$ has distribution $Po(\lambda \dot c)$.

Comment: Yes the distributions are independent with $Y_1 \sim Po(\lambda)$ and $Y_2 \sim Po(c\lambda)$.

Answer (score 1):

The pdf of $Po(c \dot \lambda)$ is just $v \to e^{-c\lambda} \frac{(c\lambda)^v}{v!}$, $v \in \mathbb{N}_0$.